# Query to find top customers in countries with greatest difference in from 2 months

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

lets say theres columns: customer_id, revenue, country, date

what is a query that would show top customers with the highest revenue growth from nov to dec?

what is a query that would show the top 100 customers in each country that has the highest growth in revenue from november in december?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the revenue growth can be using the window function `lag()`:

```
select customer_id, revenue, date, country,
       revenue - lag(revenue,1,revenue) 
                     over (partition by customer_id order by date) as growth
from turnover
where extract(month from date) in (11,12)
```

`lag(revenue,1,0.0)` will return the revenue from the previous row. If there is no previous row, it will return the current row's revenue. This results in a growth of 0 for the first row for each customer.

Now with the `growth` column this turns into a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem which is also typically solved using window functions. However as window functions can't be nested in a single query, you need to use two levels of nested derived tables:

```
select customer_id, revenue, date, country, diff_to_previous,
       dense_rank() over (order by growth desc nulls last) as rnk
from (
  select customer_id, revenue, date, country
         revenue - lag(revenue,1,0.0) over (partition by customer_id order by date) as growth
  from turnover
  where extract(month from date) in (11,12)
) t1
```

This assigns a rank for each row based on the growth. However you can't use the `rnk` alias directly in the `where` clause and that's why you use the additional level of a derived table.

So the final statement to get the customer with the highest growth is:

```
select *
from (
  select customer_id, revenue, date, country, growth, 
         dense_rank() over (order by growth desc) as rnk
  from (
    select customer_id, revenue, date, country, 
           revenue - lag(revenue,1,0.0) over (partition by customer_id order by date) as growth
    from turnover
    where extract(month from date) in (11,12)
  ) t1
) t2
where rnk = 1;
```

To get the 100 highest growth for each country you just need to change the calculation of the `rnk` to do it per country:

```
select *
from (
  select customer_id, revenue, date, country, growth
         dense_rank() over (partition by country order by growth desc) as rnk
  from (
    select customer_id, revenue, date, country, 
           revenue - lag(revenue,1,0.0) over (partition by customer_id order by date) as growth
    from turnover
    where extract(month from date) in (11,12)
  ) t1
) t2
where rnk <= 100;
```

---

<sup>`date` is a horrible name for a column. Not only because it is a keyword but more importantly it does not document what the column contains. Is that a "start date"? an "end date"? A "purchase date"? A "due date"?</sup>